# composer network ping -c PeerAdmin@airlinev81 I got this error when i ping to my business network. How to avoid Authorization failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Steps followed :**

```
step 1: composer network install -a dist/airlinev82.bna  -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 
step 2: composer network start -A PeerAdmin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f airlineAdmin.card -n airlinev81 -V 0.0.1 
step 3: composer card import -f airlineAdmin.card  
step 4: composer-rest-server -c admin@airline8 -n always -w true
step 5: composer network ping -c PeerAdmin@airlinev81
```

**Error:**

Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Enrollment failed with errors `[[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]`

**my card list:**

```
jeet@jeet-Lenovo-ideapad-300-15ISK:~/fabric-tools$ composer card list
```

The following Business Network Cards are available:

**Connection Profile:** hlfv1

```
┌──────────────────────┬───────────┬──────────────────┐
│ Card Name            │ UserId    │ Business Network │
├──────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ PeerAdmin@airlinev81 │ PeerAdmin │ airlinev81       │
├──────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ admin@airlinev8      │ admin     │ airlinev8        │
├──────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────────────┤
│ PeerAdmin@hlfv1      │ PeerAdmin │                  │
└──────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some error in this

`composer network start -A PeerAdmin -S adminpw -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -f airlineAdmin.card -n airlinev81 -V 0.0.1`

You should name the admin `admin`: `-A admin -S adminpw`
I have read this somewhere in SO but can't find it now.

Comment: I got the solution. it happens because I have t=not set authorization in the .acl file